# Can we use only the bottom mic while recording audio using iPhone 6

Tags: audio, video, iphone, microphone

For a school project, I need to record a video (60 fps) with audio recorded only from the bottom mic. The default Camera app seems to use all 3 mics while video recording, which creates a distorted sound. Is there a video recording app which allows controlling which mic to use? I am using iPhone 6

Answer (score 1):

Both [Filmic Pro](http://www.filmicpro.com/) and [MoviePro](http://www.seeitwithus.com/moviepro.htm) lets you select which mic to use for recording.